# NSImageView and resizing of window

Tags: macos, cocoa, autolayout

I have a Cocoa application. In the window's view I have placed an NSImageView. Using auto layout I have added leading and trailing spaces in such a way that the NSImageView is anchored to the view (and thus window).

The NSImageView's scaling property have been set to ScaleDown.

When I make the window larger, everything happens as expected. The image is centered in the window and does not scale up.

The problem is when I make the window smaller. Everything works until I hit the image's size. Then I can't make the window any smaller.

In other words I can only make the window as small as the image's size. What I want - and did expect by using the ScaleDown setting - is to have the image scale down with the window.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The image view's compression resistance priority is higher than `NSLayoutPriorityWindowSizeStayPut` (500). So, the image view's resistance to being compressed prevents the window from resizing.

Lower that resistance priority.